# How to generate these silly html characters at various heights / positions?

Tags: html, css, html-entities, zalgo

## See images for reference.

I wonder how to create them? What are they called? And why on earth it is possible?

- https://twitter.com/konieczny
  [image]
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/775359
  [image]
- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#comment1648264_1732454)
  [image]

Comment: I agree... Once you know what keyword to search for :)

Answer (score 1):

It's just plain text, with special unicode characters called *combining characters*:

­

h͚͔͕͍̣̙̞̃ͯt̖̗͎̩̳̻̆͑̈͐̉̐̚t͔͈̠̙̦̱͌̌͛́ͅͅp̱̞̓ͩͅ:̮̜̹̜͔̼͍ͪ̍̓ͨ͊̍ͥ/̖̮̘̰͕̯͈̱̺̓̎ͮ͐̈́/̿̍̓̑͌̔‌​̭̥̙͓̱̤͙͙ḳ̺̬̭̗͌̔ͩ͊̔̚ͅn̳͉̪̰̿ͦ̆̆o̥͎̮̠͌͋w͇̬̫̗͈̰̯̎ͤ̈́̈́ͮ͐́y͔̗͎̖̲̜͖̟̽͊ͪ͒̆̈ͪ̚ŏ̥͚̦̰͚͂̀̐ͧ̂‌​̞ù̠̩͖͓̦̆ͥ͂ͯr̜̣̝̘̬̖̲̓͛̓ͤ͛͗m͇̞̹̻̣̼͔̐̈e̖̻̲̺̩̟̙̮͑ͫ̋̇m͇̘̜̼̊ͤ̑̂e̲͉̦͉͉̓̉ͦ͂̋.̪̮ͯ͊ͪ̍̇͑͋͊̚‌​͓̺c͉͎͚͚̳̙̘̱ͤ͊͗͒͗̀ǒ̭͕̼́̈́ͅm̠͓̜͒̉/̹̳͎̯̥̪̮͗͛m̖͓̫͓͉͉̙̹̀̾͐ͧͪ̽ͥͥě̤̜͈̽̋̽ͮ̓̏̂m̻͆̊̅̎͂͆ͣ̍̾‌​͇̖̮͇̖̘̱͙e͙͍̻͕̤̾ͩ̄ͮ̈ͮͅs̘̺͕̳͂͑͒͆͐/͈͚̪̮ͨ͊ͨͯ̈́ͩ͌̚z̞͖̬͇̅ͨ̋̊ͬͩ̏ä̟͕͇͇̹̹ͤ̂̈́̂̌̒̆l̹͓̬̮̰͊̑̌̾‌​g̘̘̟͇ͣ̍̿̊̆͑̑ͅo̯̺͉͖̭ͥ̃ͣ̊̐̽

­

If you copy it in Notepad++, you will see the following:

[image: In Notepad++]

Comment: Zalgo! I was actually searching for Zombo... Everything is possible at Zombo :)